# VS Code Prettier - Code Formatter Extension not working with Create-React-App using Typescript template

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app, prettier

I am currently trying to set up an application using the Create-React-App startup package, with the TypeScript template.  The initial install of that goes perfectly fine.  However, when I try to use the Prettier- Code Formatter extension in VS Code to auto format my files on save, I get the error:

> > Invalid prettier configuration file detected. See log for details.

The log details basically just reiterate that error message.  I am unsure of what is causing this.  I have tried adding a .prettierrc file, as well as adding configs in the package.json file, all to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your vs code open File->preferences->Setting then open your setting.json and put those insede it:

```
"[typescriptreact]": {
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"editor.formatOnSave": true}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. OP does use Prettier, but it got crashed